# How to move List View Item from one list to another with drag and drop? UWP C#

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, drag-and-drop, listviewitem

**I have many List Views in an UWP application and I would want to be able to move one item from one List View to another List View**

I know about the AllowDrop or CanDragItems properties and that you need to handle some events for drag and drop to work, although I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add ListView controls by clicking Add button and move items between ListView controls, please check the following code as a sample. The following code is different from the offical [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop), it use `ObservableCollection` to complete the drag and drop operation. You could drag an item from source `ListView` item to target `ListView`, and also drag an item from original  target `ListView` to original source `ListView`.

You could click the `Add` button twice and then two `ListView` with two items are added. You can drag any item from any `ListView` control to another. If you want to keep the dragged item in the source `ListView` control, just comment the code `dragCollection.Remove(dragedItem as string);` .

For example:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> dragCollection;
private ObservableCollection<string> dropCollection;
private object dragedItem;
private ListView dragListView;
private ListView dropListView;
……

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = new ListView();
    listView.CanDragItems = true;
    listView.CanDrag = true;
    listView.AllowDrop = true;
    listView.ReorderMode = ListViewReorderMode.Enabled;
    listView.CanReorderItems = true;
    listView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "item1","item2" };
    listView.DragItemsStarting += ListView_DragItemsStarting;
    //listView.DropCompleted += ListView_DropCompleted;
    listView.DragEnter += ListView_DragEnter;
    listView.Drop += ListView_Drop;
    listView.DragOver += ListView_DragOver;
    listView.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    listView.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);

    stackPanel.Children.Add(listView);
}

private void ListView_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
}

private void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    dropListView = sender as ListView;
    if(dropListView!=null)
    {
        dropCollection = dropListView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;
        if (dragedItem != null)
        {
            dropCollection.Add(dragedItem as string);
            //If you need to delete the draged item in the source ListView, then use the following code
            dragCollection.Remove(dragedItem as string);
            dragedItem = null;
        }
    }
}

private void ListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation = (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text) ? DataPackageOperation.Move : DataPackageOperation.None);
}

private void ListView_DropCompleted(UIElement sender, DropCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    if (listView != null)
    {
        dropListView = listView;
        dropCollection = listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;

        if(dropListView==dragListView)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

}

private void ListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = sender as ListView;
    if(listView!=null)
    {
        dragListView = listView;
        dragCollection = listView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<string>;

        if (dropListView == dragListView)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(e.Items.Count==1)
        {
            dragedItem = e.Items[0];
            e.Data.RequestedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Move;
        }
    }
}
```

For more information about dragging and dropping, you could refer to the document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/drag-and-drop).

Any concerns about the code, please feel free to contact me.

Comment: And what if the List View Items are not strings, but custom List View Items (with grid with elements in their content)? What do I need to change besides `ObservableCollection<string>` to `ObservableCollection<ListViewItem>` (if that's possible)?

Comment: You just need to replace all the type parameter(`string` here) of `ObservableCollection` instances with your custom List View item. The key point is to keep the binding source of ListView as an `ObservableCollection` instance, then you could save the dragged item as a variable and drop the item to the target `ListView` by adding the dragged item to the `ObservableCollection`  of the target ListView.

Answer (score 0):

To implement dragging, you must set `CanDragItems` on the source `ListView` and `AllowDrop` on the target `ListView`. Then, you must handle `DragItemsStarting` event on the source list. Within this handler you can store the dragged data inside the `DragItemsStartingEventArgs.Data` property. Afterwards, you handle `Drop` event on the target list and retrieve the stored item values from the `DataPackage` using `DragEventArgs.DataView`.

To see all the moving parts of this in action, I recommend the official UWP samples for drag & drop which are available [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop). The first scenario of this sample show dragging items from and to a `ListView` including reordering support.

Comment: And what if it's not possible to set the ListView items due to the fact that the ListViews are generated on button click in the app? There is an add button to add a List View and I need to be able to move one item from one of the added ListViews to another one with drag and drop.

Comment: That is ok, as long as you make sure to set the mentioned properties and events on the newly created `ListView`. So for example `var list = new ListView(); list.AllowDrop = true; list.Drop += MyHandler;`